# Trying to retrieve result using linq

Tags: linq

Hi I have a table which has a column AllowStockEdit which is a bit

I am trying to check is a user has edit access and then show edit and delete buttons on a radgridview

this is the code I am using

```
    protected void AccessLevels(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LINQDataContext dc = new LINQDataContext();
    UserPermission up = dc.UserPermissions.Where(a => a.ID == (int)Session["Permission"]).SingleOrDefault();
    up.AllowStockEdit = true;
}

    /*show hide buttons */

    protected void SelectedStockGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // show the edit button when user has correct access level

            if  
            {
                Button btnEdit = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("ShowEditButton");
                Button btndelete = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("ShowDeleteButton");

                btnEdit.Visible = true;
                btndelete.Visible = true;

            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to check to see if the user has edit access if they do show the buttons

any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
 protected bool AccessLevels()
{
    LINQDataContext dc = new LINQDataContext();
    return dc.UserPermissions.Where(a => a.ID == (int)Session["Permission"]).SingleOrDefault().AllowStockEdit;

}

 protected void SelectedStockGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // show the edit button when user has correct access level

            if(AccessLevels() == true) 
            {
                Button btnEdit = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("ShowEditButton");
                Button btndelete = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("ShowDeleteButton");

                btnEdit.Visible = true;
                btndelete.Visible = true;

            }
        }
    }
```